# JS and Jquery problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

hi i got the problem the script.js gives me

```
<div id="gracze">
  <div id="10" class="char" style="z-index: 19; top: 592px; left: 608px; "></div>
  <div id="14" class="char" style="z-index: 25; top: 784px; left: 608px; "></div>
</div>
```

instead

```
<div id="gracze">
  <div id="4" class="char" ... ></div>
  <div id="10" class="char" style="z-index: 19; top: 592px; left: 608px; "></div>
  <div id="14" class="char" style="z-index: 25; top: 784px; left: 608px; "></div>
</div>
```

get_players.php

```
4/62/6
10/19/19
14/19/25
```

script.js

```
function get_players()
{
    $.ajax({   
    type:   "POST",
    url:    "get_players.php",   
    dataType: "html",  
    success:  function(data) {
        var str = data;
                var chars = str.split("<br />");
                var lol = chars.length;
                for(var i = lol; i--; ) {
                    chars[i] = chars[i].split('/');
                    var o = document.getElementById(chars[i][0]);
                    var aimt = i;
                    if (!o) {
                        if (aimt!=chars.length-1 && aimt != 0) {
                            $('#gracze').html('<div id="'+chars[aimt][0]+'" class="char"></div>'+$('#gracze').html());
                            $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("top", chars[aimt][2]*32-16+"px");
                            $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("left", chars[aimt][1]*32+"px");
                            $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("z-index", chars[aimt][1]*32);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).animate({
                            "top": chars[aimt][2]*32-16+"px", "left": chars[aimt][1]*32+"px"
                        }, { duration: 275});
                        //$('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("top", chars[aimt][1]*32-16+"px");
                        //$('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("left", chars[aimt][2]*32+"px");
                        $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("z-index", chars[aimt][2]);
                    }
                }
        }});
    setTimeout("get_players();", 1000);
}
```

I think it's because of `for(var i = lol; i--; ) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the loop to this:

```
for(var i = lol - 1; i >= 0 ;i-- )
```

Javascript array indexes start with 0 and end with the size of the array -1 (so if an array has 5 elements, the first one will have index of 0 and the last one of 4).

Your original loop starts with the size of the array, immediately decrementing it (so the last element is accessed). The loop continues until the variable decrements to 0, at which point the loop is existed, without the *first* element being used.

See [this page](http://www.openjs.com/articles/for_loop.php) about looping over arrays in javascript.

---

Additionally, this condition `if (aimt!=chars.length-1 && aimt != 0)` specifically excludes the last element. Remove the `&& aimt != 0`.

Comment: @Sonny - What is `if (aimt!=chars.length-1 && aimt != 0)` supposed to do? I would say that this condition is your issue.

Comment: @Sonny - can you be serious? Can you explain the purpose of the test? I would suggest that it is incorrect.

Comment: repaired thx for sending me that if the  && aimt != 0 cause that

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing a reverse loop, I'd use a reverse `while` instead.

```
var i = chars.length;
while( i-- ) {
    //...and so on
}
```

This will be faster, will give you the proper value of `i` inside the body of the loop, and will still terminate the loop at the proper time.

The reason this works is that I've used a post-decrementing operator for the while. This means that the value of `i` here:

```
while( i-- )
```

will always be 1 greater than it is in here:

```
{
    // ...and so on
}
```

So if the total length is `5`, you'll have the proper index `4` inside the block.

Toward the end, when `i` is `1` in the evaluation, it will be `0` in the block, indicating the last iteration, which gets the item at the first index.

The next pass will evaluate `i` at `0`, and the code in the block won't execute.

Comment: @Sonny: Replace: `var lol = chars.length; for(var i = lol; i--; ) {` with this instead: `var i = chars.length; while( i-- ) {` Everything else is the same.